# $ \partial U$ is uncountable.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ ($n\ge 2$) be a domain (bounded). How to prove that $\partial U$ is uncountable?

Domain: connected open set

$\partial U:$ boundary of $U$

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: It's false. Look at the the plane minus the origin.

Comment: What do you consider a "domain"? Just a subset of $\mathbb R^n$? Does it have to be open?

Comment: @zhw The OP is only allowing bounded sets as "domains", so the punctured plane is not allowed.

Comment: @JimBelk The post is edited after that comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a point in the set x. Take rays emanating from it. Map a point, p, on the unit circle to the last point in the boundary on the ray from x through p.
This injective.

So the cardinality of the boundary is at least as big as that of the unit circle.

Comment: Note that this only works as long as $U$ is open. For a closed counter-example, take any one-point set.

Comment: domain usually means open